# Andengine - detect collisions with multiple objects and delete them - Java

Tags: java, andengine, collision

Currently I am checking for collisions with the following updateHandler. But it does not work properly. This is maybe due to the multiple objects I have in the `platformMap` List.

```
public void registerCollisionUpdater() {
        registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {

            @Override
            public void reset() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {
                for (int i = 0; i < platformMap.size(); i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < platformMap.get(i).length; j++) {
                        PlatformSprite pl = platformMap.get(i)[j];
                        if (tBall.collidesWith(pl)) {
                            pl.destroy();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

What is the correct way to check collisions for many sprites?
How could I recognize if the bullet has hit a static body?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use a ContactListener already? If not this link might be helpful http://www.matim-dev.com/handling-collisions-between-bodies.html